# Function IFS in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I want to use `IFS` in Excel 2016, but I don't have this function.

I have few functions, with `IF`:

([image])

how can I added it?

I tried to update the Excel, but without result.

Comment: You have to embed multiple IF statements in each other if you use older versions of Excel. E.g. `=IF(X=1, 1, IF(X=2,2,""))`

Comment: I tried to use, like that, `= IF (B2 > 97, "A +", IF (B2 > 93, "A"; IF (B2 > 89; "A-"; IF (B2 > 87, "B +", IF (B2 > 83, "B"; IF (B2 > 79; "B-"; IF (B2 > 77, "C +", IF (B2 > 73, "C"; IF (B2 > 69; "C-"; IF (B2 > 57, "D +", IF (B2 > 53, "D"; IF (B2 > 49, "D-"; "F")))` , but it doesn't work

Comment: @EduardStefanescu : Obviously, you are mixing `,` and `;`... This can't work

Comment: For your IF I would use INDEX/MATCH: `=INDEX({"F","D -","D"},MATCH(B2,{0,49,53}))` I will let you put the other grades in.  Or you can build a table with the same info and use vlookup.

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: This function is available if you are an Office 365 subscriber and have the latest version of Office installed. It's also available with Excel Online, Excel Mobile, and Excel for Android phones and tablets.

From : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFS-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45

1st google result with : IFS in Excel 2016

Comment: I have the latest Excel 2016.

Comment: @EduardStefanescu Excel 2016 is different than Office 365 Excel.  This is only available in Office 365 Excel.

Comment: @EduardStefanescu : And are you an **Office 365 subscriber**??? Because it isn't in regular Excel... Please don't make us do the support of MS and read the links!

Comment: In Office 365, work, but a friend with the same version of Excel 2016, have this function.

Comment: @EduardStefanescu : Ok, so contact MS support (find how somewhere on there site), we are not here to do that

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your version:

> This function is available if you are an Office 365 subscriber.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFS-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45

Comment: That's interesting - i have office 365, and Excel2016 but that IFS() is not available... will do some checking 'cos it could be handy...

Comment: @SolarMike see my answer if it explains your issue

Answer (score 0):

Officialy, IFS function is available only to Office365 subscribers, as @R3uK posts in his answer.

## however

There are people owning Office365 without this function in Excel 2016. Maybe the reason is the same as for SEQUENCE function:

> Note: September 24, 2018: The SEQUENCE function is one of several beta
> features, and **currently only available to a portion of Office Insiders**
> at this time. We'll continue to optimize these features over the next
> several months. When they're ready, we'll release them to all Office
> Insiders, and Office 365 subscribers.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90

Since it is officialy available in 2016 version already, Office 2016 update for Office365 subscribers should solve the problem.